# How can I ensure that I always run something when a non-interactive shell is launched?

Tags: bash

Let's say I have a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
whoami
```

I would like to have it so that when I execute this script, `foo` is always printed before its execution. In fact, I would want `foo` to be printed before execution of any script (not just this example).

I tried playing around with the `bashrc` file however this doesn't seem to work:

```
case $- in
    *i*) echo "foo";;
      *) return;;
esac
```

Comment: `echo foo` in the script would print `foo`, but this would not be "before execution". Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. [Edit] the question if there is. Why do you need `foo` to be printed *before* actual execution? Before execution of any script? or before execution of this exact script only?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I essentially want to run a custom bit of code before any script is executed (specifically, I want to set a `trap`)

Comment: Do you really want non-interactive or did you mean interactive? Bashrc is not read by non-interactive shells (unless you have explicitly set .profile to source it, as is the case in Debian and its derivatives), and the code you show would echo `foo` only in interactive shells since you're looking for `i` in `$_`. And what do you mean by "before any script"? What's a script? Shell scripts only? Perl? Python?

Comment: @terdon yes, non-interactive. And only shell scripts

Comment: @Foo which shells? Bash? Sh? Zsh? Tcsh? Csh? Fish? All users? Specific users? What of system calls launched by other scripts? If a perl or python script runs an sh command, for example? And you really want to exclude non interactive shells that are running anything other than a shell script? Please edit your question and give more context. Your OS will also likely be relevant.

Comment: @terdon just bash scripts

Comment: Please EDIT your question and add all these details. It will be very, very complicated to do this only for bash, and we still need to know if this should also happen when bad is called by another program. If you explain _why_ you want this, what you are really trying to achieve, that would make it easier to answer.

Comment: As others have said, can you edit your question to explain **why** you want to do this. It sounds a good way to break your system. For example lsb_release tells you various information about your system. Installers can run it to help decide what to do based on its output. If you have an implementation in bash, and it now outputs an unexpected `foo` then installation scripts are going to be confused, and may do the wrong thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~/.bashrc` is only interpreted by non-login interactive invocations of `bash` not running in posix mode¹

For a file that is interpreted by every invocation of bash (excluding ones running in posix mode), you can use `$BASH_ENV`:

```
$ cat ~/.bashenv
if [[ $- != *i* ]]; then
  echo foo
fi
$ export BASH_ENV=~/.bashenv
$ bash -c 'echo bar'
foo
bar
```

If that `echo foo` is only meant to be interpreted by bash *scripts*, that is when `bash` is invoked as `bash /path/to/file` (like with a `#! /bin/bash` shebang or [the more correct `#! /bin/bash -` form](/q/351729)) and not other forms of non-interactive shell invocations (like `bash -c code` (as done by `xterm`, `vi`, GNU `parallel`... when running `$SHELL` code), or `bash < file`) you can change the `[[ $- != *i* ]]` to `[[ $- != *[ics]* ]]`.

The equivalent for zsh is `~/.zshenv` (or `$ZDOTDIR/.zshenv`).

All csh/tcsh invocations read `~/.cshrc` (`~/.tcshrc`) unless passed `-f` (which is why most csh scripts have a `#! /bin/csh -f` shebang).

ksh used to honour `$ENV` but that was stopped for non-interactive shells for security reasons (`$ENV` processing for interactive invocations is still a POSIX requirement for `sh` and the only way to have a shell customisation file there).

---

<sup>¹ Like when invoked as `sh` or when there's `$POSIXLY_CORRECT` or `SHELLOPTS=posix` in the environment or if called wih `-o posix`. `~/.bashrc` may also be interpreted by bash shells when invoked even non-interactively over ssh with some builds of bash. bash startup file processing is a bit of a mess.</sup>

Comment: See also: [What is the Bash equivalent to .zshenv?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/695870)